# Add soft hyphens in a CMS: getting it to work in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, content-management-system, hyphenation, soft-hyphen

`&shy;` is awesome, especially because it works in all popular browsers. You put it in the middle of a word, which tells the browser that the word *may be* broken in that place. If it does get broken there, a hyphen appears. If it doesn't, the character remains invisible.

But it's not very easy to use for content authors: you have to go into the HTML to add it. Even if you *can* add it in a CMS, you can't see where it is as soon as you inserted it.

So I went ahead and declared an inline style in my CMS for my authors to use. They can select part of a word, for example `<span class="shy">communi</span>cation`, and then a css rule will magically add the `&shy;` using an `:after` pseudo-element! And with some CMS-specific CSS I can give that tag a dotted underline to show that it's got one of those soft hyphens. Works in Firefox and IE8+. Neat.

But the hyphen doesn't appear in Google Chrome! It breaks the word, but there's no dash. I knew it didn't support the `hyphens` css property, but it does normally support `&shy;`.

But all right, so I removed the css style and wrote some javascript to add ­ upon load. Using jQuery, I tried both `.append` and `.after`. I even tried `innerHTML += '&shy;'`. None of them work! How disappointing...

How to work around this?

Comment: Looks like solving the problem. You should instead consider how to instruct content authors to type the SOFT HYPHEN character itself. (There are many different approaches to that, but it’s not on-topic at SO.)

Comment: Being able to type that character only solves half the problem though: it may be fine for posts that are only created once, but it is only a temporary solution for pages that are edited more often. During an edit the next day you may have forgotten where you put the character, or if you put one at all. Even if you do know, it is not obvious to remove, while being easy to accidently and unwittingly remove. That's why I wanted to make it visually apparent.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution while writing this question.

`&shy;` seems to work in Chrome only if there is another character right after it (*and* before it). The issue above is that the `&shy;` character is always the last one within the tag. So I added a space and then closed that space with css. Unfortunately this does not work with a css pseudo element, so I still needed javascript.

I did need to use browser detection because adding the space made it stop working in Internet Explorer and Firefox. (using `&nbsp;` makes it work in Firefox, but not IE)

```
$(".shy").each(function(){
    this.innerHTML += '&shy; '; // add the soft hyphen (for all browsers)

    // Only Chrome has an issue
    if(/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        this.innerHTML += ' '; // add a space
        $(this).css('margin-right', '-.26em'); // close the gap from the space
    }
});
```

To be used like this:

```
<span class="shy">communi</span>cation
```