# Soft hyphens in line of inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I need to insert hyphens when there is a line break between inline-block elements.

This is what I tried:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px">
  <span>This is a long se</span>&shy;<span>quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se</span>&shy;<span>quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se</span>&shy;<span>quence of spans.</span>
</div>
```

But hyphens are not shown, at least in Chrome. I need a result like this, in which they are correctly shown, but without the spans.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px">
  <span>This is a long se</span>-<span>quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se</span>-<span>quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se</span>-<span>quence of spans.</span>
</div>
```

When using inline-block adding spaces (see [Add soft hyphens in a CMS: getting it to work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976771/add-soft-hyphens-in-a-cms-getting-it-to-work-in-chrome)) do not work:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px">
  <span>This is a long se</span> &shy; <span>quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se</span> &shy; <span>quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se</span> &shy; <span>quence of spans.</span>
</div>
```

Any idea, without using JavaScript? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it without the spans around the `&shy;` entities: Spans are inline elements by themselves, so they interupt the word (which is why you don't see a hyphen), which `&shy;` does *not*

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 140px">
  <span>This is a long se&shy;quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se&shy;quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se&shy;quence of spans.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px">
  <span>This is a long se</span> &#8209; <span>quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se</span> &#8209; <span>quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se</span> &#8209; <span>quence of spans.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This always shows the hyphens, even with greater width. I'm looking for hyphens that only are shown when needed.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a [Hyphenation Opportunity](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#hyphenation) because there aren't characters to break. At least this is how Chrome chose to implement the standard.

[More info](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/css-hyphens)

Comment: I understand this, and it's even more evident in my real use case, where I have a more complex inline-block. I'm looking for a technique to simulate the hyphening. I would prefer avoiding JavaScript (in case JavaScript is needed I think I can sort it out by myself).

Answer (score 0):

[Hyphenator.js](https://github.com/mnater/hyphenator) seems like an option.

Works great on Chrome, has polyfill for legacy browsers and rerenders hyphens on resize. [Demo here](http://mnater.github.io/Hyphenator/).

I've seen your comment about avoiding JS, but I don't think that it's possible, cause final text-size defined only on client-side and can be affected by user's browser settings.

Comment: Thank you. It seems too much work for this, I replied with a simpler (JavaScript) way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with JavaScript. HTML:

```
<div style="width: 200px">
  <span>This is a long se<span class="hyphen">-</span></span><span>quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se<span class="hyphen">-</span></span><span>quence of spans.</span>
  <span>This is a long se<span class="hyphen">-</span></span><span>quence of spans.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hyphen {
    display: none;
}

.hyphen.hyphen-shown {
    display: inline;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    var handler = function(evt) {
        var hyphens = document.getElementsByClassName("hyphen");

        for (var i = 0; i < hyphens.length; i++) {
            var hyphen = hyphens[i];

            hyphen.className = "hyphen";

            var element = hyphen.parentNode.parentNode;
            var element = parent.nextElementSibling;

            if (parent == null || next == null) {
                continue;
            }

            var py = parent.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
            var ny = next.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

            if (Math.abs(py - ny) > 1) {
                hyphen.className = "hyphen hyphen-shown";
                var py2 = parent.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

                if (Math.abs(py - py2) > 1) {
                    // The hyphen made the parent be shown on next line.
                    hyphen.className = "hyphen";
                }
            }
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handler, false);
```